# How can I prevent the user from dealing with the status bar?

Tags: android, statusbar

I making a locker application.

I want to make it like 'go locker', which prevent the user from touching or scrolling down the status bar.
I won't use "Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen", 'status bar permission' and i'm finding the way to make it possible.

How can I make the status bar prevent from dealing with touch events?

Comment: in go-locker maybe they implemented a custom status bar.

Comment: @Tiko Is that possible to make a custom status bar does the same act that normal status bar does?

Comment: you just have to implement the events by yourself, but i guess you don't need that because you want to prevent status bar from dealing with touch events in the first place so it could be just a custom view.

Comment: @Tiko but I can't create the view that can cover status bar and can dispatch touch events from it. I used [WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY) so i could cover status bar, but i couldn't get touch events..